# Distinct column with primary key column

Tags: sql, distinct

Distinct column count differs when adding the primary key column in the Select query

The count distinct for supplier_payment_terms is 110, but when adding the PK column, the count changes to thousands.

```
select distinct  supplier, unique_id from indirect_spend;
```

I expect the same record count of 110 when including the PK column in the select. The Select must only include the unique_id of the supplier.

Comment: So you have thousands of records in the `supplier_payment_terms` from 110 suppliers. Maybe you expect to have 110 payments? What does this table actually contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation to get *example* primary keys:

```
select supplier, min(unique_id), max(unique_id)
from indirect_spend
group by supplier;
```

Comment: I got the unique_ids of the records in the select distinct. Thank you, big help.

Comment: I also got the same number of rows as my distinct. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

"I expect the same record count of 110 when including the PK column in the select"

Then you expect wrong.  SELECT DISTINCT causes all ***rows*** appearing in the result to be distinct, i.e. no duplicate ***rows*** in the result.

Besides.  Imagine two rows (supplier-id unique-id) (1 2) and (1 5).  You say you expect only one row in the result.  How is the system going to determine which one of the two rows to deliver ?